# Xamarin - Resize frame2 based on content, except image

Tags: forms, xamarin, size, adaptive-design

This is my XAML:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding GalleryList}" x:Name="cv"  SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="CollectionView_SelectionChanged">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                    Span="1" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentView Padding="5">
                        <forms:Frame2 CornerRadius="8"  
                           HasShadow="True"
                           ShadowRadius="5"    
                           ShadowColor="LightGray"
                           Padding="0"
                           Margin="5"
                           MinimumHeightRequest="160">
                            <Grid Padding="0" Margin="0" ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <forms:Frame2 CornerRadius="8"                                            
                                   Padding="0"
                                   Margin="0"
                                   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="5"
                                   IsClippedToBounds="true"
                                   BackgroundColor="#EEEEEE">
                                    <ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="{Binding BgImg}" Margin="0" CacheDuration="10" Aspect="AspectFill" Opacity="0.5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="5">
                                        <ffimageloading:CachedImage.Transformations>                                        
                                            <fftransformations:BlurredTransformation Radius="3"></fftransformations:BlurredTransformation>
                                        </ffimageloading:CachedImage.Transformations>
                                    </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
                                </forms:Frame2>

                                <Label Padding="3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Text="{Binding GalName}" FontSize="Subtitle"></Label>
                                <Label Padding="5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Text="Photographer: " FontSize="Small" ></Label>
                                <Label Padding="3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding PhName}" FontSize="Default" ></Label>
                                <Label Padding="5" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Text="Code: " FontSize="Small" ></Label>
                                <Label Padding="3" x:Name="PhotographerCode" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding PhCode}" FontSize="Small" ></Label>
                                <Label Padding="3" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding GalCode}" FontSize="Small"></Label>
                                <Button Padding="10" Margin="3" Grid.Row="1" CornerRadius="8" Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Text="X" FontSize="Default"  TextColor="White" Clicked="Button_Clicked" ClassId="{Binding GalCode}" BackgroundColor="DimGray" BorderColor="black"  ></Button>
                            </Grid> 
                        </forms:Frame2>
                    </ContentView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

For the Frame2 I have a `MinimumHeightRequest` of 160 because the labels can be multilined. I would like my Frame to be as small as possible, but to expend based on its content. Currently it is working, but it is also extending based not he image I use as background. I would like it to expand only based on the content and not the image. How can this be done?

Thank you

Comment: Have you try to put the `CachedImage` without `forms:Frame2`?

Comment: yes it did not work.. at the end i had to increase everything to 200px and then give fixed sizes to all rows instead of *-

Comment: You put the `CachedImage` and one Label in the same row and column of grid. What does the image do here? Please check the position in grid.

Comment: the cached image stretches over the whole grid.. its used as background..

Comment: The Height of `RowDefinition` could change the size of background image. Set all the `RowDefinition ` like below: `<RowDefinition Height="0.2*" />`. You could check the screenshot. https://imgur.com/rTepxEh